# Nginx resverse proxy for prams in an expressjs application

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have got a route in expressjs application with the following code.

...

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          // debug(`The req  is ${req.params.id}`);
          const data = await getSuperHerors(req.params.id);
          res.send(data);
        } catch (err) {
          next(err);
        }
      });
```

...

I want to setup my nginx revere proxy to forward on the id.
The conf file for nginx is here
...
server {
root /var/www/html;

```
    server_name example.biz; # managed by Certbot
    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

            # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1$is_args$args;

            # set $upstream http://localhost:3000;
            # proxy_pass $upstream/$1$is_args$args;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.biz/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.biz/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}

server {
    if ($host = example.biz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.biz;
    return 404; # managed by CertbotWhat is wrong with my reverse proxy file.

}
```

...
What is wrong with my reverse proxy file.
For now I have put it back to its original but I have tried to use the configs behind the comments.

Joseph Shanahan

Comment: The `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;` statement will pass the entire requested URI to the upstream server (including arguments) - there is no need to add them to the statement. Also, `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1$is_args$args;` will not work as `$1` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, you are right all requests were forwarded.
I went back and had a look at my setup and found something else wrong.
Cheers
Joseph Shanahan